# Laylat al-Qadr : working the next day

Tags: practical-islam, laylat-al-qadr, tahajjud

I'm living in France and I really want to pray all the night, especially since today is the *Laylat al-Qadr*. However, I must be at work at 8:00 am, and the last pray (*Icha*) starts at midnight.

How can I manage this? Should I really pray all the night?

Answer (score 1):

In the Name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

However this question is opinion-based, I'll give my sincere opinion and advice, and you can choose to take mine or not.

Taraweeh is something special. But to pray from 'Isha until Fajr, is not easy to do, especially when you have work to do early in the morning, like in your case. In that case I would sleep now, so when you're in the Masjid, you've got enough energy to keep up, and to go to work. If you sleep now, you won't have to do that later. And you don't have to pray all night. You can also do 2, or 3 times Taraweeh and call it a day. This is often what people do, especially the young people, who've got school afterwards. If you can however pray all night, you should do it. The best thing to do in days like this, is to ask your boss if you can take some days off. Ramadan is the month of getting closer to Allah (SWT), and we shouldn't forget this. (Energydrinks might help also.)

I hope this answers it, and God knows best. Again, this is an opinion-based question, so here's my opinion-based answer.

Jazakullah Khairan, peace be unto you.

Answer (score -2):

u can manage it...
here is the example frst u prepare a list tht wht to recite in laylatul qadr like surah mulk, nafil rakats and then sleep for sometime...now try to wake up at sehri before 45 mins and perfrm the tahajjud salah nd pray to Allah that due to ur wrk u r nt able to pray all night...Allah tabarak talah is very merciful he will inshallah give u the benefits of todayz night. Aftr eating sehri...again go to bed and wake up few mins befr whn u r leaving ur Apartmnt for wrk bcz of Ramadan u dnt have to eat brkfst...tht is also the benefit...and i know u wll feel lttl dizzy at wrk but aftr rtng frm wrk u cn rest at ur home...
Allah kmows better
Remember me in ur prayer bro.